# "calinvite" url scheme in ios?

Tags: ios, url, calendar, url-scheme

How can i use this url-scheme in practise?

calinvite   calinvite:eventid=id

(source: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/NSURL)

is it possible to add a calendar entry with this URL scheme?

thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use it. Because it is `private`.

You can only use the URL schemes that are public, if you use these private url schemes in your app, the app will be rejected from `AppStore`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. i've found another way with calling a extern php script, maybe for some of you this will be of use: 
https://gist.github.com/jakebellacera/635416